# Parameter for getDeclaredConstructor method

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection, constructor, parameter-passing

How can I pass parameters to getdeclaredconstructor methos if the parameter of constructor is a two dimentional list of string?
If the parameter is String I can use String.class.
But what should it be for 2 dimensional List of string?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the type of the parameter of the constructor is `List<List<String>>`, you can just use `List.class`. The generic type of the list will be ignored.

In case you wonder what it would return if you would have a constructor that takes a `List<String>` and another constructor that takes a `List<List<String>>`, that is not even allowed in java.